# How to improve download performance of web page

Tags: javascript, html

I have implement a feature of calculating download speed of internet connection. Using Ajax I am calling a php file from server which opens a big file (say 30MB) and flush the data to web browser (client). This works fine with Mozilla and Chrome but with IE 8 it gets stuck (hang) in the middle since the data that is server is flushing might be huge. I have used xdomainrequest in IE 8. Please let me know is there any to improve the download script for IE so that I can get proper download values.

Following is the code snippet.

```
function myfun()
{
    try
    {   
        if(BrowserType=="MSIE")
        {
          xhr=new XDomainRequest();
          xhr.onerror = err;
          xhr.ontimeout = timeo;
          xhr.onprogress = progres;
          xhr.onload = loadd;
         // xhr.onabort = stopdata;
          xhr.timeout = 500;            
        }
        else
            xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(BrowserType!="MSIE")
            {
                var iLen = bufferedData.length;
                if(iLen <= 100000)  
                  bufferedData=bufferedData+xhr.responseText;
            }

            if (xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
            {
                //alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }       

        xhr.open("GET", "http://myserver/donload.php", true);
        xhr.send();
        if(BrowserType=="MSIE")
        {
            var data=xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    catch(e)
    {   
        alert(e);       
    }
}
```

Or is there any alternative to this approach.

Regds

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery, it has a ajax method, which works in every Browser. 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

And this will help you also: http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying an old school method, use **JQuery** which is more easy way and reliable.

This is how it looks, very simple, in fact you don't need this much messy codings. it will work fine with IE almost any version

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url, // your url to pass parameters
  data: data, // your parameters
  success: success, // call back result function
  dataType: dataType
});
```

**Go [Here](http://jquery.com/download/) and download most recent version, try implementing.**

**Here is the [beginner](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-post.htm) tutorial for you**